# Rebuild linux raid array?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid

I'm going to be building a media server soon and I want to know how hard it would be to rebuild an array in the event of an ssd failure. Here's what I'm doing. I'm going to have a 128GB SSD boot drive running Linux and then I'm going to have two 6TB drives in raid 1. In the event the SSD dies and I lose my configuration how hard will it be to rebuild the array? Should I just stay away from the SSD boot drive? I'll be doing a kernel raid with mdadm. Thanks.

Comment: ditch the ssd boot drive; it is of no benefit to a media server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raid configuration is stored on the raid devices themselves. You could take your RAID drives out of that computer and put them into any computer and `mdadm` would be able to start the RAID off them. Problems start when the metadata on the drives themselves is damaged.

You could include your SSD in the RAID 1, using 128G on the HDDs and `write-mostly`. You'd still get SSD read performance but HDD write performance off such a RAID. On the upside you'd survive SSD failures.

For full SSD performance, just make backups. (You need them anyway).

Comment: Well I feel stupid. I thought the config was stored on the OS drive. So that answered that.

Comment: The configuration on the OS drive is usually limited to assigining the UUID of the RAID to a specific `/dev/mdX` number. It usually also contains a mail adress to notify you of RAID failures. By itself, it is not sufficient to actually access the RAID data.